# Python equivalent to picking first non-null argument

Tags: javascript, python

In JavaScript I can do

```
const foo = bar || baz || bloop || blop || bleep || null
```

If I want `foo` to be equal to the first one of the above arguments that is not falsey / null

Is there an idiomatic Python equivalent? I was just going to loop through a list of args, but thought I'd check.

Comment: `foo = bar or baz or bloop or blop or bleep or null`, well, probably `... or None`

Comment: Hi Teddy!  Did my answer solve the problem for you, or is there something you'd still like to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@zvone is correct.  For instance:

```
banana = True
tom = 4
hotdog = None
goo = hotdog or tom or banana
shazam = banana or hotdog or tom
```

In this example, `goo` is `4`, and `shazam` is `True`.  So you can mix types!  Cool stuff.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong!  I thought that JS allowed only comparison of like objects.  I should have double checked before making the qualitative claim about "coolness".

Comment: Gotcha.  Removed initial coolness comparison comment from the answer.